# Word generator for ruby testing

Tags: ruby, testing

Does someone know of a good ruby testing library for generating English (or maybe also those Latin "lorem ipsum") words? Another nice thing would be to specify some additional options (e.g. the word length, only use names). Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check out [Faker](https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker). For example,

```
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > Faker::Lorem.sentence
  => "Enim molestiae incidunt rem ipsum perferendis beatae excepturi tenetur."
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > Faker::Name.name
  => "Agnes Hand II"
```

Comment: I like Faker a lot, it has tons of options.

    >> "Using #{Faker::Company.bs} for     
      #{Faker::Company.catch_phrase}"
    => "Using streamline enterprise architectures for Upgradable    
      disintermediate software"
    >>

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of the gem `lorem_ipsum_amet` which you'll find here:

- Rubygems: https://rubygems.org/gems/lorem_ipsum_amet
- Homepage: http://yagooar.github.io/lorem_ipsum_amet/
- Source code: https://github.com/yagooar/lorem_ipsum_amet

For now, it only produces Latin text, but you can use various parameters. These are the most common methods:

```
LoremIpsum.lorem_ipsum # default Lorem Ipsum text

LoremIpsum.text # alias for #lorem_ipsum

LoremIpsum.placeholder_image(400, 300) # placeholder image

LoremIpsum.lorem_ipsum(50) # 50 characters

LoremIpsum.lorem_ipsum(paragraphs: 4) # 4 paragraphs

LoremIpsum.lorem_ipsum(words: 100) # 100 words

LoremIpsum.lorem_ipsum(words: 100, html: true) # 100 words, paragraphs joined by <br />

LoremIpsum.lorem_ipsum(50, join: "\r\n") # join paragraph with a custom string

LoremIpsum.random # one random paragraph starting at a random position

LoremIpsum.random(paragraphs: 4) # 4 random paragraphs

LoremIpsum.short # a short text

LoremIpsum.long # a long text
```

There is also a Rails integration for rendering blind texts & placeholder images in your views:

ERB:

```
<%= text_area_tag 'placeholder', lorem_ipsum %> 
<%= image_tag placeholder_image(200, 300) %>
```

HAML:

```
%p= lorem_ipsum(paragraphs: 5) 
= image_tag placeholder_image(250)
```

Some more features are planned (adding multiple language support). Just check out the repository for more details on the current and future features.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at Randexp http://github.com/mattetti/randexp

It gives you a tight control on what's generated